# how to detect if user click no or yes on window default alert?

Tags: javascript

I wrote the following code to set the site as the homepage:

```
document.body.style.behavior='url(#default#homepage)';
document.body.setHomePage('http://www.abc.com');
```

When the user clicks this, an alert box appears asking the user whether or not he wants to set the site as his homepage.

How can I detect which choice the user made?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5000418/how-to-handle-yes-no-dialog-that-was-pop-up-using-javascript-on-button-click

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can't because there's no return value...
2. ... on browsers that support it, which I believe is just certain versions of IE, and apparently that support is sketchy ...
3. ... but you really shouldn't, because it's extremely annoying when a site asks a user that (the answer is almost always **no**).

Comment: have to agree with @Bryan.  Nearly always the answer will be no.  And in most cases where the user wants to make the page his/her homepage, they know how.

Answer (score 2):

Use [isHomepage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms531394%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) to check if it is the homepage. If so, the user pressed yes.